# How to compute cyclic notation (23)(1)

Tags: group-theory, notation, permutations

I seem to become confused whence computing simple cyclic notations as such.

From my understanding, the rule goes by starting from the right and to the left. However by doing this I only end up with (1), which i doubt since the answer is (23).

A hint or perhaps an explanation would be very helpful and much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to explain where you go wrong if you describe in more detail how you get the result to be $(1)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm , well, i simply start by stating (1 and seeing that it only maps to itself, i close the bracket at that instant (1). And since i have to start from the right side, which i have already stated (as 1). I just simply end there.

Comment: x @Sai: That procedure will find _the cycle that contains 1_. If you have elements still unaccounted for after you get back to the starting point, you must restart the algorithm at one of those to find the cycles _they_ are part of.

Comment: Ok, @HenningMakholm now i understand. So every element must be accounted for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(23)(1) = (1)(23)$ since the cycles are *disjoint*, and disjoint cycles commute.

$(23)(1)$ means $1$ maps to $1$, $2$ maps to $3$, and $3$ maps to $2$.  When an element maps to itself, we can omit such a one-cycle, and it is implicitly understood that the missing element maps to itself.

So, the most brief way of denoting $(23)(1)$ is simply $(23)$.

Comment: thanks for reminding me that "disjoint cycles commute". Is it okay to picture (1) as sort of an identity, which allowed (23) to generate itself?

Comment: @Sai82: Yes, any cycle of length 1 is a way to write _the_ identity (not just "sort of", but the actual identity permutation).

Comment: Yes, Sai82. As I see Henning beat me to answering ;-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm and amWhy, i can see things clearly now. Thank you :)

Comment: Luckily the system has detected a serial of downvote! It's weird $14$ downvotes!!

Comment: @Sami I just woke up and saw that reversal: I knew someone (or two) was/were down-voting my posts fairly regularly for awhile, but not all at once; I flagged for a moderator two days ago, who deemed it a valid flag, and who said would look into it. I hope the "culprit" got warned!!